# iOS 7.0.3 - Awful performance on iPad 3 whilst excellent results in the Simulator

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, ios-simulator

The program I am developing perform relatively well in the Simulator (I have a MBPR/15" with 4xcpu, 16GB Ram&500G SSD) but is awfully slow on my iPad3.

Xcode doesn't show some huge CPU activity  and Memory usage stays at ~25MB.

What could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you profiled with Instruments?

Comment: Excellent results in the simulator is indicative of...nothing at all.  As @Moshe said, you need to profile your application to find the hotspots.  Although, it should be noted that the iPad 3 was a bit of a failed experiment for Apple.  It's graphics hardware is not powerful enough for its screen.

Comment: Simulator runs the app built for x86 and you are using a very fast and powerful computer. You can expect a noticeable difference in performance with iPad 3. The same you will find driving a Ferrari or a chip urban car. Try to optimize your code for not so steroided CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulator, is a simulator, that means that your application will run with the hardware of your mac, and your mac is pretty on steroids :-) . Simulator behave very differently for the actual devices just few exaple:

- sim is case insensitive
- sim is not GPU accelerated (games performs better on device)
- it lacks some hardware: camera, motion sensors, GPS

To check why your app is performing slow on iPad you have a lot of tools in instruments.

- Time Profile
- Allocations
- Core animation performance

You've got also some tools on the simulator, like checking blending, not aligned pixels, off screen rendering... thay can make difference in general graphic performace

Comment: Thanks, is there a good manual to get acquainted with the latest iOS Instruments?

Comment: Hi, there are different tutorial out there, you can start from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode , it is not really updated, but still valid. Evenf if your memory footprint seems OK, I will start with allocations